# 411 Response on Post from WSO2 API Manager to REST endpoint

Tags: json, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have setup a REST endpoint in WSO2 AM that calls out to another REST endpoint.  When the call is made I am receiving a 411 response code.  The request contains a JSON body, the content type and accepts header are set to application/json.  I can curl the backing service that WSO2 is accessing directly with the same params and it works correctly.  It seems that WSO2 AM is stripping or not sending the content-length.

Why is the content length not being sent to the REST endpoint that is being accessed?

Comment: On what API Manager version are you trying? are you sending a put or post request?

Comment: POST and version 1.10

Answer (score 0):

Sending content-length is disabled by default because it can cause performance degradation. But you can enable it by adding following to the api's insequence. (see https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions on adding custom sequence to an api)

```
<property name="COPY_CONTENT_LENGTH_FROM_INCOMING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" scope="axis2" value="true"></property>
```

following is a sample sequnce

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="contentLengthadd">
    <property name="COPY_CONTENT_LENGTH_FROM_INCOMING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="FORCE_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" scope="axis2" value="true"></property>
</sequence>
```

This sequence will get the content length from incoming request request and pass it the request header to the backend.

you can read more about these two properties in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-FORCE_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH

Comment: I created a file called WSO2AM--Ext--Out.xml to try to make it a global param.  I copied the XML sample above into that file, changing the name to match the file name.  I did this based on the docs at the link you mentioned.  After doing this and restarting I still receive a 411.  A caveat, I am testing this out in the APIM Store and it is doing a Curl on the try it out.

Comment: @MikeH The sequence should be in the insequence and not in the out sequence. So the sequence name should be WSO2AM--Ext--In.